# Ruby on Rails - get MySql DB size

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know the current size of my MySql DB, to get that data I use the following methods:

```
def self.calculate_total_db_size
    sql = "SELECT table_schema AS 'database',
                  sum( data_length + index_length ) / ( 1024 *1024 ) AS size
                  FROM information_schema.TABLES
                  WHERE ENGINE=('MyISAM' || 'InnoDB' )
                  AND table_schema = '#{get_current_db_name}'"
    return  perform_sql_query(sql)
  end



def self.get_current_db_name    
    return Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]["database"]
end

def self.perform_sql_query(query)
     result = []
     mysql_res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
     mysql_res.each_hash{ |res| result << res }
     return result
end
```

this works great in my development and staging environment, but from some reason when i run it in production the query doesnt return any value, if i take the MySql query and run it manually on my production DB I get the correct values. why cant i do it through  the application in production?

any thoughts?

Comment: Try logging queries on server if it runs correct query.

Comment: @Ran thanks for the tip on this. If anyone else is trying to do this in Rails 4, I had to change `mysql_res.each_hash{ ... }` to `mysql_res.each{ ... }` (and it looks like `map` works too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some more logs and that helped me pinpoint the 
problem, I was using: 
Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]["database"] 
which returns an empty string when I was in production and not in any other 
environment, I guess it is because in my database.yml there's a link to the 
development setting under production (what makes the production settings the 
same as the dev). 
anyway, since i dont want to change my database.yml file i just changed the 
way im getting the database name. 
now it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I'll wager $1 it's a permissions issue in production. Log into your production server and fire up the db console (go into your rails dir and type rails db to ensure you're using the same user as your app) and try to select from tables in the information_schema database.

The mysql account you're using in production most likely doesn't have access to the records you want in the information_schema database.